# Function signatures in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The `std::function` class is templated in such a way that when we want it to wrap a function like the following:

```
void printInt(int integer)
{
    std::cout << int << '\n';
}
```

We use a `std::function<void(int)>`. Until recently I thought this was an odd nuance of the class, but [a class I found](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11) while searching for delegate implementation in C++ uses a similar syntax.

What exactly *is* `void(int)`, and what do we call it in technical terms? It seems to be the standard way of saying "*a function that takes an int, and returns void*" in codespeak, but my gut instinct says that's horribly oversimplified.

Secondly, I've noticed that when I see templates using this syntax they use variadic templates to allow multiple function signatures to be matched. From the link above:

```
template <typename T> class delegate;

template<class R, class ...A>
class delegate<R (A...)>
{
...
```

What is the reason for declaring the function as such instead of simply using the following:

```
template<class R, class ...A>
class delegate
{
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The template parameter to `std::function<Signature>` is simply the type of a function, i.e., its signature. It uses the same notation as any function declaration except that it isn't named and the name is left out. You may have come across function pointers which use the same notation but the function signature is used for a pointer.

The reason `std::function<Signature>` (and apparently `delegate<Signature>`) are implemented using template specialization is to yield a nicer type:

```
template <typename T> class function;
template <typename R, typename... Args>
class function {
public:
    R operator()(Args...);
    // ...
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class other {
public:
    R operator()(Args...);
    // ...
};

int main() {
    function<int(double, char)> f;
    other<int, double, char>    o;
}
```

Since the primary template for `function<T>` takes *one* type as argument, using the specialization the argument can be a normal function type. On the other hand, the same isn't done for `other<T...>` which, thus, gets a list of types.

It is worth nothing that `std::function<T>` objects can be passed around quite easily without any need to deal with many template arguments: since the function's signature is just a type, this class template takes just one template argument.

Comment: So that part is *actually* called a function signature? Guess I knew the term after all... Good explanation, thanks!

Comment: function pointers use a *similar* notation. They are of the form `void(*)(int)`.